# Interface for associative object array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tuples, associative-array, unions

I have an object like so:

```
var obj = {
    key1: "apple",
    key2: true,
    key3: 123,
    .
    .
    .
    key{n}: ...
}
```

So `obj` can contain any number of named keys, but the values must all be either string, bool, or number.

How do I declare the type of `obj` as an interface in TypeScript? Can I declare an associative array (or variadic tuple) of a union type or something similar?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
interface MyType {
    [key: string]: string | boolean | number;
}

var obj: MyType = {
    key1: "apple",
    key2: true,
    key3: 123
};
```

Comment: Did you find this in the docs? I have searched (certainly not everything though …), to no avail. Link would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I've dug deeper into the docs after reading this question and [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213971/4306828), and came up with a terrific solution!

I've used [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to create a **Dictionary Interface**!

```
interface Dictionary<Type> {
   [key: string]: Type;
}
```

Which you can **(re)use** like so:

```
const myNumbers:Dictionary<number> = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3
};

const myStrings: Dictionary<string> = {
    key1: 'Lorem',
    key2: 'Ipsum',
    key3: 'Dolor'
};

const myElements:Dictionary<HTMLElement> = {
    button: document.querySelector('#button'),
    input: document.querySelector('#input')
};
```