# Update initial useState of object - TypeScript , ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

Hey guys i am currently new at TypeScript and i am trying to have a state value that conatins only objects . At the moment i have an array of objects like this :

```
[{ Ananas: "A", Banana: "B" , Citroen: "C"}]
```

, but the ultimate goal would be to have something like this :

```
{ Ananas: "A", Banana: "B" , Citroen: "C"}
```

I was defining my initial state like this

```
const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
```

And now i try something like this , but i think is not the correct way to have initial state of objects only

```
 const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState({});
```

My update function is as simple as that

```
  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
  
    setSelectValue((selectValue: any) => {
      const newSelectValue = [...selectValue];
      if (!newSelectValue[0]) newSelectValue[0] = {};
      newSelectValue[0] = { ...newSelectValue[0], [e.target.value]: e.target.name };
      return newSelectValue;
    });
  };
```

But as i said from above i want to update the state value to contain only objects and not an array of objects . So i wonder how can i do that.  Thanks upfront

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213971/6463262

Comment: Could you share your component's cod which use `handleChange`?

Comment: I think you're trying to define an object as state and update the value of its properties, Am I true?

Comment: yes thats the whole idea , but the moment i am doing an array of object update 
`<Select name={keys[i]} onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}>`
This is my component where the `handleChange` is used

Comment: @PandaMastr I answered the question. Please see the answer and if there's problem, please say to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation and my understanding your question, you can do something like this. If there's any problem, please say to contribute and improve the answer:

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = React.useState({});
  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    var index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.target[index].text);
    setSelectValue({
      ...selectValue,
      [e.target.value]: e.nativeEvent.target[index].text
    });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectValue);
  }, [selectValue]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
        <option value="A">Ananas</option>
        <option value="B">Banana</option>
        <option value="C">Citroen</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit jovial-sun-w0z76]

Comment: your object is not updated when you click . It remains empty

Comment: @PandaMastr it changes when you change the select's options not with clicking on the select.

Comment: @PandaMastr Have you tried this approach?

Comment: i found another approach , but still in your sandbox when you click on the selected value it does not update the object at all

Comment: @PandaMastr I've attached sandbox by mistake.

Comment: @PandaMastr Please see the new sandbox and pay attention to console.log

Comment: Yes now it is updating . I am marking this answer as success for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Just get first value from array.

```sh
let myArr = [{ Ananas: "A", Banana: "B" , Citroen: "C"}] 
let newArr = myArr[0]
console.log(newArr)

// { Ananas: 'A', Banana: 'B', Citroen: 'C' }
```

Comment: Yeah , but the idea is on `handleChange` to create only objects and NOT an array of objects . Your way is a bit of workaround

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your types first.
It's very hard to follow what you are actually doing and where the problem is.
Where is e.target.value coming from? What type is selectValue?
Let TypeScript help you and don't fight it with :any ;)

If I got it right I would tackle it somehow like that

```
type Fruits = Record<'Ananas' | 'Banana' | 'Citroen', string>
export const OkCool = () => {
  const initialData: Fruits[] = [{ Ananas: 'A', Banana: 'B', Citroen: 'C' }]
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<
    Record<string, Fruits> | undefined
  >()

  const selectFruit = (key: string, fruitsArray: Fruits[]) => {
    // destruct from Fruits[] to get Fruits
    const [fruits] = fruitsArray
    setSelectedValue(value => ({ ...value, [key]: fruits }))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        placeholder="key"
        onChange={e => selectFruit(e.target.value, initialData)}
      />
      {JSON.stringify(selectedValue)}
    </>
  )
}
```